# Estimate $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\cos q_j}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to estimate the following sum? The sum is:
$$S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\cos q_j}$$
where $n\in\mathbb N$, $q_j\in\mathbb R$ and $|q_j|< \frac{\pi}{4}$ for all $j\in\mathbb N$. I think that this is a too hard problem but... what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cosine is even let ${0}<q_j<{\pi\over4}\implies1<\sec q_j<\sqrt2$. Therefore
$$
n< S_n<\sqrt2n
$$